# Don't understand this Scheme function for making a balanced binary tree

Tags: tree, scheme

I have trouble understanding these functions:

```
(define (list->tree elements)
  (car (partial-tree elements (length elements))))

(define (partial-tree elts n)
  (if (= n 0)
    (cons '() elts)
    (let ((left-size (quotient (- n 1) 2)))
      (let ((left-result (partial-tree elts left-size)))
        (let ((left-tree (car left-result))
            (non-left-elts (cdr left-result))
            (right-size (- n (+ left-size 1))))
        (let ((this-entry (car non-left-elts))
              (right-result (partial-tree (cdr non-left-elts)
                                          right-size)))
          (let ((right-tree (car right-result))
                (remaining-elts (cdr right-result)))
            (cons (make-tree this-entry left-tree right-tree)
                  remaining-elts))))))))
```

I guess `partial-tree` divides the whole list into half, and recursively makes subtrees of each half. But I am totally lost with all the `car`/`cdr` involved. Specifically:

1. Why is `car` needed in `(car (partial-tree elements (length elements)))`?
2. Why does the `left-result` in `(let ((left-result (partial-tree elts left-size)))` take the whole list `elts` instead of half of it?
3. What is `remaining-elts` in this:

   ```
   (cons (make-tree this-entry left-tree right-tree)
         remaining-elts))))
   ```

I tried to use a test case `'(1 3 5 7 9)`, but when I see the recursive call `(partial-tree elts left-size)`, I am totally confused and don't know what the `left-result`, `left-tree`, `right-result` would be.

I would really appreciate hints on how to think about this.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got wondered how recursion works, then it's always better to write down all steps (with small amount of input). Suppose we have `(1 3 5 7 9)` as an input of the `list->tree`. Then the `partial-tree` would do the following steps:

```
;; > (partial-tree '(1 3 5 7 9) 5)
;;   left-size : 2
;;   >> *1 (partial-tree '(1 3 5 7 9) 2)
;;     left-size : 0
;;     >>> *1 (partial-tree '(1 3 5 7 9) 0)
;;       >>>> n == 0
;;       <<<< '(() . (1 3 5 7 9))
;;     left-result   : '(() . (1 3 5 7 9))
;;     left-tree     : '()
;;     non-left-elts : '(1 3 5 7 9)
;;     this-entry    : 1
;;     right-size    : 1
;;     >>> *2 (partial-tree '(3 5 7 9) 1)
;;       left-size : 0
;;       >>>> *1 (partial-tree '(3 5 7 9) 0)
;;         >>>>> n == 0
;;         <<<<< '(() . (3 5 7 9))
;;       left-result   : '(() . (3 5 7 9))
;;       left-tree     : '()
;;       non-left-elts : '(3 5 7 9)
;;       this-entry    : 3
;;       right-size    : 0
;;       >>>> *2 (partial-tree '(5 7 9) 0)
;;         >>>>> n == 0
;;         <<<<< '(() . (5 7 9))
;;       right-tree     : '()
;;       remaining-elts : '(5 7 9)
;;       <<<< *3 '(#(() 3 ()) . (5 7 9))
;;     right-result : '(#(() 3 ()) . (5 7 9))
;;     right-tree   : '#(() 3 ())
;;     remaining-elts : '(5 7 9)
;;     <<< '(#(() 1 #(() 3 ())) . (5 7 9))
;;   left-result   : '(#(() 1 #(() 3 ())) . (5 7 9))
;;   left-tree     : #(() 1 #(() 3 ()))
;;   non-left-elts : '(5 7 9)
;;   this-entry    : 5
;;   >> *2 (partial-tree '(7 9) 2)
;;     left-size : 0
;;     >>> *1 (partial-tree '(7 9) 0)
;;       >>>> n == 0
;;       <<<< '(() . (7 9))
;;     left-result   : '(() . (7 9))
;;     left-tree     : '()
;;     non-left-elts : '(7 9)
;;     this-entry    : 7
;;     right-size    : 1
;;     >>> *2 (partial-tree '(9) 1)
;;       left-size : 0
;;       >>>> *1 (partial-tree '(9))
;;         >>>>> n == 0
;;         <<<<< '(() . (9))
;;       left-result   : '(() . (9))
;;       left-tree     : '()
;;       non-left-elts : '()
;;       this-entry    : 9
;;       right-size    : 0
;;       >>>> *2 (partial-tree '() 0)
;;         >>>>> n == 0
;;         <<<<< '(() . ())
;;       right-result   : '(() . ())
;;       right-tree     : '()
;;       remaining-elts : '()
;;       <<<< *3 '(#(() 9 ()) . ())
;;     right-result   : '(#(() 9 ()) . ())
;;     right-tree     : '#(() 9 ())
;;     remaining-elts : '()
;;     <<< *3 '(#(() 7 #(() 9 ())) . ())
;;   right-result   : '(#(() 7 #(() 9 ())) . ())
;;   right-tree     : 
;;   remaining-elts : '()
;;   << *3 '(#(() 1 #(() 3 ())) 5 #(() 7 #(() 9 ())) . ())
;; < '(#(() 1 #(() 3 ())) 5 #(() 7 #(() 9 ())) . ())
```

I've the `*1` is the first `partial-tree` call which construct left tree. `*2` is the second `partial-tree` call which construct right tree. Then `*3` is the returning value of non zero input. To make it easy to understand, I've also put what kind of values are set to each variables.

Now the answer of your questions:

1. Because the result of `partial-tree` contains 2 elements, constructed tree and remaining elements (which is null).
2. The left tree should always take the first element of input list as it's entry. Then the rest of elements are passed to right tree construction. Remember, this is recursion so each right tree construction will reduce the element and call the left tree construction.
3. It's remaining element to be constructed in the next iteration. In the end it will be null.

Hope this would help your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Ad 1)

`(partial-tree elts n)` returns a pair of two values: the first values is a tree with the first `n` elements of `elts` and the second value is a list of the remaining elements of `elts` (which can contain more elements than `n`).

Ad 2)
  The size `left-size` determines how many elements in the list that are used.
  There is no need to trim the list first.

Ad 3) Elements n+1, n+2, etc in `elts`. I.e. the elements not used to make the tree.

```
#lang racket
(define (list->tree elements)
  (car (partial-tree elements (length elements))))

(define (make-tree this left-tree right-tree)
  (match (list left-tree this right-tree)
    [(list '() x '()) (list   x)]
    [(list '() x r)   (list   x r)]
    [(list  l  x '()) (list l x)]
    [(list  l  x r)   (list l x r)]))

(define (partial-tree elts n)
  (if (= n 0)
      (cons '() elts)
      (let* ([left-size      (quotient (- n 1) 2)]
             [left-result    (partial-tree elts left-size)]
             ; left result is now a pair of
             [left-tree      (car left-result)]     ; a tree with (n-1)/2 elementer
             [non-left-elts  (cdr left-result)]     ; a list of elements not in left-tree

             [this-entry     (car non-left-elts)]   ; the (n-1)/2+1'th element

             [right-size     (- n left-size 1)]     ; n - left-size - 1

             ; note: left-size + 1 + right-size  = n

             [right-result   (partial-tree (cdr non-left-elts) right-size)]
             [right-tree     (car right-result)]    ; a tree with n - left-size - 1 elements
             [remaining-elts (cdr right-result)])   ; element n+1, n+2, ... of elts
        (cons (make-tree this-entry left-tree right-tree) ; a tree with n elements
              remaining-elts))))                          ; element n+1, n+2, ... of elts

(partial-tree '(a b c d e f g h) 1)
(partial-tree '(a b c d e f g h) 2)
(partial-tree '(a b c d e f g h) 3)
(partial-tree '(a b c d e f g h) 4)
(partial-tree '(a b c d e f g h) 5)
(partial-tree '(a b c d e f g h) 6)
(partial-tree '(a b c d e f g h) 7)
(partial-tree '(a b c d e f g h) 8)
```

Output:

```
'((a) b c d e f g h)
'((a (b)) c d e f g h)
'(((a) b (c)) d e f g h)
'(((a) b (c (d))) e f g h)
'(((a (b)) c (d (e))) f g h)
'(((a (b)) c ((d) e (f))) g h)
'((((a) b (c)) d ((e) f (g))) h)
'((((a) b (c)) d ((e) f (g (h)))))
```